# Kivy RecycleView: RecycleView child not begin updated

Tags: kivy, kivymd, kivy-recycleview

See this is my simple app

```
class CustomKid(MDCard):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        self.size_hint_y = None

        self.height = self.minimum_height 

        self.radius = 25

        

        self.content = Builder.load_file('/storage/emulated/0/Ecommerce/Screens/item_card.kv')

               

        self.add_widget(self.content)

        

    

#--------------------kids_section_ends--------------------#   





class Example(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        

    def kids_tops(self):

        import threading 

        from functools import partial

        from kivy.clock import Clock  

        path = 'tops'

        scr = 'kts'

        rv = 'rvkt'

        self.kids.ids.rvkt.data = [{"viewclass":"CustomKid"} for i in range(1,6)]       #adding 5 cards

        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.update_cards_data,path,scr,rv),1)

        

    

    def kids_bottoms(self):

        import threading 

        from functools import partial

        from kivy.clock import Clock  

        path = 'bottoms'

        scr = 'kbs'

        rv = 'rvkb'

        self.kids.ids.rvkb.data = [{"viewclass":"CustomKid"} for i in range(1,6)]     #adding 5 cards

        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.update_cards_data,path,scr,rv),2)

        

    

    def update_cards_data(self,path,scr,rv,*args):

        from kivymd.toast import toast

        from kivy.clock import Clock  

        try:            

            for layout in self.kids.ids[rv].children:

                print('this is layout:',layout)

                for child in layout.children:

                    print('this is child:',child)

                    

            self.kids.ids[rv].refresh_from_data()

            self.kids.ids.ksm.current = str(scr)

        except Exception as e:

            print(f"Error updating cards data: {e}")
```

As you can see i've added 5 cards then i called update_cards_data to see the layout and childs. Normally i should get 1 layout and 5 childs for 5 cards right? No matter how long time i pass in the clock  I'm getting

```
this is layout: <kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout.RecycleGridLayout object at 0xb7646ca0>

this is child: <__main__.CustomKid object at 0xb6ea5d48>
```

But when i immediately call the function second time right after the first call i got

```
this is layout: <kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout.RecycleGridLayout object at 0xb7646ca0>

this is child: <__main__.CustomKid object at 0xb6ea5d48>

this is layout: <kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout.RecycleGridLayout object at 0xb7646ca0>

this is child: <__main__.CustomKid object at 0xb506ae60>

this is child: <__main__.CustomKid object at 0xb509a3e0>

this is child: <__main__.CustomKid object at 0xb518b920>

this is child: <__main__.CustomKid object at 0xb6ea5648>

this is child: <__main__.CustomKid object at 0xb6ea5d48>
```

i want this to happen in first call

This is a similar code which is doing the job as expected then what's wrong with my app.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

import threading 

import dialog

data = None

from kivymd.toast import toast

KV = Builder.load_string(

    '''

my code

'''

)





class CustomCard(MDCard):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        self.size_hint_y = None

        self.height = self.minimum_height 

        self.radius = 25

        

        self.content = Builder.load_string('''

my code

        ''')

        

        

        self.add_widget(self.content)

        

    

        

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        return KV

        

    def kids(self):

        dialog.open_dialog(self)

        self.root.ids.rvk.data = [{"viewclass":"CustomCard"} for i in range(1,6)]     

        threading.Thread(target=self.update_cards_data).start()

        

    def update_cards_data(self,*args):

        

        for layout in self.root.ids.rvk.children:

            print('this is:',layout)

            for child in layout.children:

                print('this is:',child)

        self.root.ids.rvk.refresh_from_data()

        



MainApp().run()
```

Please help me to solve this problem